# HP ProLiant ML350 G6 Server

Tags: windows-server-2008, raid, hp, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array

I have a HP ProLiant ML350 G6 Server. I installed windows server 2008 standard edition. There are 60 clients connected to this server.

The server only detects one HDD and I have 2 146gb HDDs. I read about RAID mirroring and would like to set it up on my server.

Do I need to configure my BIOS settings to enable RAID? What is the best approach to this?

Comment: There are several different types of RAID that could be done depending on what hardware you have available.  What RAID controller did you get with that server.  I believe there where a few options.

Comment: What have you tried to do so far? HP's technical documentation is quite good so if the answer to my question above is "nothing" at least see if the HP site has any setting up RAID guides - what RAID controller does the server have?

Answer (score 4):

The HP ProLiant ML350 G6 is what we use at work. The RAID is configured automatically by the RAID controller card when the machine is first switched on and the level of RAID is determined by the number of disks. So with 4 disks you get RAID 5 with two you get RAID 1. It states in the HP documentation the RAID level that will be applied to your drives (pg. 93).

http://bizsupport1.austin.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c01711832/c01711832.pdf

You are only seeing one HDD as RAID has configured the two disks into a logical one for you automatically. If you need to alter the settings you'll need to use the RAID utility and re-install the OS.

**Update**
Edited to include updated info on default RAID levels. I was wrong and sloppy and didn't check my facts; ewwhite was correct.

Comment: It would actually default to RAID5 with 4 disks...

Comment: @ewwhite Thanks, you are correct. I don't know where I read the RAID 1+0 from. I found the docs and page where this is detailed and update my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Your server should have had a version of HP's 'Proliant Support Pack' installed on it, it's basically a bunch of hardware specific drivers and tools that get installed as one big install. You could check if this has been installed via Control Panel and the Installed Software bit.

If it's been installed then you should have a HP tool ready called 'HP Array Configuration Utility', it's a Windows tool that helps you setup and tune disk arrays.

Now yours is pretty straightforward setup and you should hopefully see the two disks, bound together into a single RAID 1 mirrored array and presented to the Operating System as a single 'logical disk'. If you can check that and it looks that way then you're doing fine, the hardware is doing the work and you're protected, it'll even alert you if there's a disk problem.

If it's not like that then come back and tell us how it's setup and we'll try to help ok.

Answer (score 1):

If you see a single disk the RAID is automatically build on first boot.

If you have installed HP Proliant Support Pack compatible with your model, you can use "Array Configuration Utility to see the status of the RAID"