# HP HP ProLiant ML350 G6

Tags: windows-server-2008

I have two HDD of 146 gb each one, during the installation of Windows server 2008 I manage not to see the second disk, only one is accessible, can-you tell me how to proceed to get back the second.

Comment: You posted this originally here: http://serverfault.com/questions/364792/hp-proliant-ml350-g6-server Were the answers there not appropriate? You need to give more info as to why your question is different.

Comment: The answer there don't give me the way to restore my second disk, I can see it in the console of the hp array manager, but not under my computer.

Comment: By default it has been set up as a RAID array. You don't use the second disk. Please read the article on [RAID at wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID)

Comment: So I can only manage and use 146gb of the first one?

Comment: Basically yes. RAID 1 is mirroring. So the data on disk 1 is mirrored transparently onto disk 2.

Comment: Of course, you could set it up so the capacity of both disks are useable and appear as one disk, although this is called RAID0 and highly, highly recommended against.

Comment: I suggest you get some basic IT courses/server administration courses before proceeding. This is basic knowledge, you will run into more difficult problems than setting up/understanding RAID.

Answer (score 4):

If you have two 146GB disks in a mirrored paid (RAID 1) then you'll only ever see one drive from the operating system, both drives are acting as one, that's what mirroring is.

Comment: If this is a server and you only have 2 physical disks, this is a *good* thing.